# checkboxes without form tags , no checked checkboxes found

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, checkbox

so i've been working on this problm for like 2 days , i've tried all the solutions i found here
my problm is that i'm using checkboxes without form tag and i want to get the checked boxes into an array and return that array  so i can insert the answers afterwards into a database but all i get is empty array even though i check

```
function recherche_salle ($conn,$datte,$begin,$end) 
{ 

$salle_libre= array(); 
$position=0; 
$str='';
$sql= "select  * from time_report_ where  new_date = '".$datte."' and  ('".$begin."' BETWEEN debut AND fin or '".$end."' BETWEEN debut AND fin)
UNION 
select  * from  events where  new_date = '".$datte."' and  ('".$begin."' BETWEEN debut AND fin or '".$end."' BETWEEN debut AND fin);"; 
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
$resultscheck = mysqli_num_rows ($results); 

if ($resultscheck>0)  
{  
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) 
  { 
    array_splice( $salle_libre, $position, 0,$row['Salle']); 

    $position= $position+1;

  } 
} 

  $image= implode("','", $salle_libre);
   //echo $image; 
   $sqll= "SELECT DISTINCT Salle FROM liste_des_salles WHERE Salle NOT in ('$image') limit 1;";
   $resultss = mysqli_query($conn,$sqll); 
   $resultscheckk = mysqli_num_rows ($resultss); 
   if ($resultscheckk>0)  
 {  echo ("voici la liste des salles libres" ."<br>");
    while ($roww= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultss)) 
   {   
       $str ='<br/>'.$roww['Salle'].'<input type="checkbox" value='.$roww['Salle'].' name="check[]" >'; 


    }















 }

    return $str;    

}
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function open_script() 
{     var items=document.getElementByName('check[]');
   var selected="";
   for (var i=0; i<items.length;i++) 
   {
    if (items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked==true) 
         selected+=items[i].value+"\n";

   } 
   alert(selected);
} 

<button onclick="open_script()"  id ="submit-form">submit </button> 
</script>
```

Comment: maybe it helps others to understand your problem better if you can describe why you cannot add form element to your html and what you have tried so far

Comment: i cannot add a form tag because this function searches in database based on past information  i brought by filling a past form, meaning if i add a form tag , those informations i got  from the first form will be lost , i tried javascript to get th array  instead of isset and the array is always empty

Comment: @WISSEMAMROUCHE how can you use $_POST, if you are not using form tag ?

Comment: @RakeshJakhar so how can return what's in check[] array ? i've tried with java script , shall i post what i did ?

Comment: @WISSEMAMROUCHE yes post here what you have did so far

Comment: @RakeshJakhar done , i've edited the post , check it out please

Comment: After getting the selected valus, you can append that to the current url using query string and retrive using $_GET, foxemaple domain.com?selectedin=1,2,3, tp retrive $_GET['selection']

Comment: Could you please clarify your solution, my javascript function isn't working , i dnt get any selected values ..